# Drag ImageView in a Grid Puzzle to swap with another ImageView in the same GridView

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a puzzle that lets you drag the puzzle part to another part in the puzzle. This drag event shall swap the 2 parts (Images in my case).

I made the first part of the puzzle by making a GridView that contains the puzzle parts as ImageViews and a blank position. So, clicking on an image checks if it is neighboring the blank position. If it is neighboring, they swap. Otherwise, nothing happens because this part can not move.

Can anyone suggest how can I change "**clicking**" the image to "**moving**" the image to do the swap operation?

Answer (score 2):

I put together a drag-and-drop grid view that you can get here:

https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

You'll have to change the animateGap(...) and reorderChildren() methods to get your intended behavior, but it should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [onclicklistener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to get the clicked image.
To 'move' the image try using `addviewat()` and `removeview()` functions on [gridview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) to remove
and add the views.